# pdfmake-wrapper how to write a line with multiple style

Tags: pdfmake

I'm trying this library which is a wrapper of pdfmake and I can't find how to make multiple styles inline, such as this example:

**I've been struggling** on this for a *while*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just found the answer to my question:

```js
new Txt([
   new Txt('I\'ve been struggling').bold().end,
   ' on this for a',
   new Txt('while').italics().end
]).end
```